# Iterate over JSON

Tags: json, freemarker

I'm having troubles in iterating over a JSON object from the response of a REST API.

This is the code I use:

```
<#assign row=table_subject.rows[0]>

<#if row?is_sequence>
  <#list row as c>
    ${c}
  </#list>
<#elseif row?is_hash_ex>
  <#list row?keys as key>
        <#list row[key] as rk>
          <#list rk?keys as rkk>
            ${key} - ${rkk}
          </#list>
        </#list>
  </#list>
<#elseif row?is_string>
  ${row}
</#if>
```

> For "#list" list source: Expected a sequence or collection, but this
>   has evaluated to a number (wrapper: f.t.SimpleNumber): ==> row[key]
>   ... ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: #list row[key] as rk Reached through ...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row[key]` gives the value from the key-value pair, so it's is not (or not necessarily) listable. You don't need two `#list`-s nested inside each other there either: you already have the key (`key`) and the value (`row[key]`). But there's a nicer way of listing a hash (since FreeMarker 2.3.25):

```
<#list row as key, value>
   ${key} - ${value}
</#list>
```

Comment: I have version 2.3.23 :(

Comment: Upgrade FreeMarker to the latest, 2.3.x-s are fully backward compatible. Using old versions can cost more of your time. If you really can't  upgrade, then just list the keys, and use `row[key]` as the value, as I said above.